Strange behavior of lombok
I have application based on Spring Boot 3.2 where I am using newest available version of lombok.
I have following entity:
@Data
@Entity
public class AppUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private boolean active;
}

Also I have a service to maintain AppUser and in that service I am calculating if user should be active or not:
@Service
public class UserService {

    public AppUser processAppUser(AppUser appUser) {
        ...
        appUser.setActive(verifyUserActivity());

        //here some other staff 
        ...
    }
}

Interesting part is the line "appUser.setActive(verifyUserActivity())". When program enters UserService.processAppUser then appUser.active is true. Then it goes to the line where setActive method is called. I set breakpoint at this line. I evaluate method verifyUserActivity() by debugger and it returns me false. So I expect to have appUser.active=false. But then when I jump to next line, it is still true.
Funny thing is that for some records it is setting value correctly, but for some records it is keeping original value of active field. Any ideas why it happens like that?

Minimal, reproducible example, please. Generating getters and setters is likely the most basic and mostly used functionality of lombok. You can be certain that it's not broken. The problem is most likely in verifyUserActivity().

Show verifyUserActivity() for sure, if it is returning a non-constant state then we can't be sure your test call and the actual call match. Otherwise, it helps to be specific about which lines you're jumping to after your breakpoint (for our sake).

It seems like a control of the state of your attribute. Whether 'active' starts with a 'false' value and it seems like the value is changed to true, and if 'active' is private, it indicates that the Lombok symbol to set was created correctly.

I'm making an hypothesis, since I don't know all the code around the appUser.setActive(verifyUserActivity()) call: it may depend on the usage of @Data annotation on the entity and the interaction of the generated methods (in particular, the equals and the hashCode) with the jpa engine.
It's a good practice not to use @Data on entities, and use this set of annotations:
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class AppUser {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private Integer id;

  ...
}

In this way, you are creating the equals and hashCode methods that rely on the identifier only, instead of the whole set of attributes, that may lead to misintepretation of the entity instance by the jpa engine, and so ad incorrect managing of attributes.

Solutions and reviews:
Using log:
Before and after the line appUser.setActive(verifyUserActivity()), log the active value. This will help you know if the active value changes after setting.
log.debug("Before setting active: " + appUser.isActive());
appUser.setActive(verifyUserActivity());
log.debug("After setting active: " + appUser.isActive());

Check changes of objects in Hibernate:
If you are using Hibernate, check if AppUser is not in detached state. You can return the object to persistent state before the changes with entityManager.merge() and then apply the changes.
Synchronization check:
If the code runs in a multi-threaded environment, use proper synchronization to avoid concurrency problems. This can include using keywords like synchronized or other Java synchronization mechanisms.
